# Problems with loading inputAccessoryView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview, accessoryview

I have an app which simply consists of an UITextView. Once the app loads, the keyboard appears and an AccessoryView is loaded on top of the keyboard so as to dismiss it.

This worked splendid until I decided that I don't want to load the keyboard when the app loads. The problem is that whenever I try to edit the text, the app crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS). I don't really understand why this should be. Here is my code -- the passage is marked which crashes the app:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

// Make the keyboard appear when the application launches.
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
// [textView becomeFirstResponder];}
```

And then:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)aTextView {


    // this crashes app if no keyboard is loaded in viewdidload:

        if (textView.inputAccessoryView == nil) {
        textView.inputAccessoryView = accessoryView;    
        self.accessoryView = nil;

}


    return YES;
}
```

If I comment out the last if statement, the app works ... but I don't have my accessoryView. May it be possible that I've done something wrong in InterfaceBuilder? accessoryView is a separate view in my ViewController. It's properly connected, though (and it does work perfectly if I start with the app with keyboard on).

Any ideas would be very much appreciated. Sorry if this is obvious, but I'm still a beginner and these things cause huge headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors happen when you try to send a message to an object that has been deallocated.  Make sure that when you set your ivars you are calling retain if you use a convenience method that returns an autoreleased object.

If this does not work, you can look into using NSZombieEnabled to track where you are sending a message to a deallocated object.

I found a couple guides you could take a look at:

http://www.fromconcentratesoftware.com/2007/08/09/nszombieenabled-for-the-debugger-adverse/

http://collateraldamag3.blogspot.com/2009/11/iphone-tutorial-nszombieenabled-and.html

Comment: Thanks, really helpful! Well, it turns out that I copied code from Apple's sample for the AccessoryView and there is declares the accessory view as `@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UIView *accessoryView;` I now have `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *accessoryView;` and the app does not crash anymore. What exactly is the difference between retain and assign in this case? Apple loaded a accessoryView nib, while my accessoryView is a View of my ViewController nib -- is this the reason?

Comment: @n.evermind the difference between assign and retain properties is in the synthesized setter methods.  For assign, the setter just assigns the ivar the value passed in, for retain, the setter releases the old value, sets the ivar to the new value and calls retain.  For more information, you can read the [Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) documentation from Apple